# Android communication to external modem

Tags: android

I new to Android embedded technology. I am working on Android device to external modem communication.
 There will a external modem connected to Android device with USB.
now need to run modem command on external modem using Android application.
Should i start with http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/ or http://source.android.com/accessories/index.html. Is there any other way to achieve it.

Please let me know your comments based that i will go forward.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like you have chosen to pursue a private application-level handling of the modem rather than to patch it into the android install as "the" source of connectivity.  In that case, you would probably use the Android USB host API - the question of directly using it or using something like that wrapper would depend on if the wrapper is (nearly) compatible with your modem.  Given that the ttyACM scheme originates with modems (before being borrowed for Arduino-type gadgets) that seems at least possible, but you would have to check the details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can provide me some lib or sample code for same?

Answer (score 0):

I work in a project to make a telephone caller blocker using old 56k serial modem connected to an Android TV stick using an usb to serial adapter. I use USb terminal apk to senh Hayes AT commands to the modem, and it works flawlessly. I can configure the modem with AT#CID=1 to retrieve caller id data. The final process must include a self config part to make the modem act as caller id, a database part, that stores calls and compares with black and white list numbers, and a on hook modem command to block the call. I think that a very beginner android developer can reach it easy, but I have no ability in android. In arduino, I have made the same system working flawlessly.